# error while installing lsb-release package

Tags: xubuntu, dpkg, lsb-release

I tried to install lsb-release using sudo apt install lsb-release and I'm getting this error:
**Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)**

what is this dpkg error and how to resolve it?
Is it necesary to install this package to run python(Image processing) codes..or can we continue without it?

Comment: dpkg almost for all errors return error code (1). So what's the actual error?

Comment: I'm totally new to Linux and I thought dpkg module has some error in it...Thanks for pointing out..I'll try to find out what the actual error is.

Comment: In the post you have written *I tried to install lsb-release using sudo apt install lsb-release and I'm getting this error:*, if the error is while installing it must occur again. Try `sudo apt install lsb-release` in terminal and paste the whole and exact error message you'd receive.

Comment: This was the error:                                                                                         
 "Errors were encountered while processing:
 tzdata"                                                                                                                    and I'm getting the same error while I'm running sudo apt upgrade

Comment: Please paste the **exact** output to question body. One line error message sometimes is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

#### lsb-release is usually installed by default

To check if `lsb-release` package is already installed use:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

#### Error may apply to all packages

The error message may apply to all packages, not just `lsb-release`. From:

- [How To Solve “sub process usr bin dpkg returned an error code 1″ Error in Ubuntu](https://itsfoss.com/dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1/)

These are the most common steps to solve the error:

#### Method 1: Reconfigure Package Database

The first method you can try is to reconfigure the package database. Probably the database got corrupted while installing a package. Reconfiguring often fixes the problem.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

#### Method 2: Use force install

If a package installation was interrupted previously, you may try to do a force install.

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer...the post you've share did help a lot..

Comment: Doesn't fix the issue on debian 9...